# v4l2 camera device ID keeps changing after streaming for an extended period of time

Tags: usb, webcam, camera, v4l2

I am trying to stream video with multiple cameras on the Jetson Nano Developer Kit. While streaming for a longer period of time, one of the cameras randomly kept freezing.

So I checked the available devices thinking there might be a connection problem but found the device ID was changed.

```
> v4l2-ctl --list-devices
vi-output, imx219 8-0010 (platform:54080000.vi:4):
    /dev/video0

USB 2.0 Camera (usb-70090000.xusb-2.1):
    /dev/video1

USB 2.0 Camera (usb-70090000.xusb-2.4):
    /dev/video2
```

I am using one CSI (Raspberry Pi camera) and two USB cameras. The device IDs of the USB cam was 3 and 2 before.

What happened and how can I keep the USB ID values consistent?

Comment: My guess here is the USB ports might be going to sleep after an extended period of time. And when they come back online, the USB cams are assigned different device IDs. Or perhaps the camera themselves go to sleep after a period of time and such. Also, what is CSI? Is that referring to [CSI Linux](https://csilinux.com)?

Comment: No, CSI raspberry pi camera. Understood the problem. thanks for helping. @Giacomo1968